# Get XY coordinates masking area in image

Tags: android

I want to get XY coordinates of masking area from image, with respect to the device and want to draw a chosen image from my galary to the mask area on touch event.

Have a image with two mask area , when i touch the first mask area want to load a image from galary and need to draw it in the first mask area.

right now I can able to draw the images in these mask areas using on button click event by two separate buttons with respect to the masks. These mask areas are calculated using Photoshop and been used from asset while drawing in canvas.

Some times image may contains multiple masking areas hence I want to know the XY coordinates of the masking area so that I can draw the chosen image in the specific mask area.

getleft and getTop values are loaded from asset
 These values are calculated using photo shop and placed in the asset
img_left_2=765; img_top_2=245 ; img_right_2=1145 ; img_bottom_2=843

Heres is the code:

public void loadImagefromGallery(View view) {

```
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.buttonLoadPicture1:
        pictureIndex = 0;
        break;
    case R.id.buttonLoadPicture2:
        pictureIndex = 1;
        break;

    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, view.getId() + " : " + pictureIndex);
    if (pictureIndex != -1) {
        Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Constants.RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
    } else {
        prepareImage();
    }

}

private File getTempFile(String templateId, int pictureIndex) {
    return new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
            "temp_" + templateId + "_" + pictureIndex + ".jpg");
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        if (requestCode == Constants.RESULT_LOAD_IMG
                && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            System.out.println("Gallery Image URI : " + imageUri);

            outPutFile = getTempFile(template.getId(), pictureIndex);
            CropUtil.cropImage(this, imageUri,
                    template.getPictures()[pictureIndex], outPutFile);

        } else if (requestCode == Constants.RESULT_CROP_IMG) {
            try {
                if (outPutFile.exists()) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "temp image : " + outPutFile.getPath());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error while save image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

public void prepareImage() {

    ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(template.getWidth(),
            template.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);

    for (int i = 0; i < template.getImageCount(); i++) {
        File tempFile = getTempFile(template.getId(), i);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "tempFile.exists() : " + tempFile.exists());
        if (tempFile.exists()) {
            String imgDecodableString = getTempFile(template.getId(), i)
                    .getPath();
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Preparing image : " + imgDecodableString);
            Bitmap originalImage = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                    originalImage.getWidth() + ","
                            + originalImage.getHeight());



            mCanvas.drawBitmap(originalImage,
                    template.getPictures()[i].getLeft(),
                    template.getPictures()[i].getTop(), null);
            recycleBitmap(originalImage);
        }
    }

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OVER));

    Bitmap imageMask = Util.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.template1_mask, template.getWidth()/2,
            template.getHeight()/2);
    mCanvas.drawBitmap(imageMask, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(null);

    mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
    mImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    mImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
    mImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#BED1CF"));

}

private static void recycleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled()) {
        bitmap.recycle();
        bitmap = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can use view.get(x) and view.get(y).can you put some or explain in detail

Comment: hey @u can't get the bitmap postition of x and y,but you can get the position of view.use imagview.setontouchlistner and get the x and y event and apply to the bitmap

Answer (score 0):

Use on touch listener to get the X and Y position

```
   @Override
       public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
  //  mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    handled = false;
    actionIndex = event.getActionIndex();
    CustomTextview touchTextView;

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.e(TAG, "Down");
            xTouch = (int) event.getX(0);
            yTouch = (int) event.getY(0);
            // check if we've touched inside some Bitmap
            touchTextView = getActiveTextView(xTouch, yTouch);

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            Log.e(TAG, "Pointer down");


            xTouch = (int) event.getX(actionIndex);
            yTouch = (int) event.getY(actionIndex);


            break;


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
            handled = true;




                xTouch = (int) event.getX(actionIndex);
                yTouch = (int) event.getY(actionIndex);

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
           se;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

            break;

        default:
            // do nothing
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

enter code here
```

Comment: Yes I can able to get the X,Y position of the screen, But these values are different from the asset values which i have configured in the asset while drawing the canvas.
e.g  : asset value : img_left_2=765; img_top_2=245 ; img_right_2=1145 ; img_bottom_2=843

OnTouch event vlaue :  x = 200,  y = 300.769 ( some values depends on the position of the screen)

Hence I am not able find the which mask has been touched

Comment: @JegadeepV when ever u set something into imagview ,the imageview use  'Scaletype'.,it can shrink and enlarge of your bitmap depends on screen

Comment: let me know how can I get the start and end position of mask area irrespective of device

Comment: @JegadeepV  mCanvas.drawBitmap(imageMask, 0, 0, paint);

Comment: onSizeChanged(int, int, int, int), you can use this method to get the your view screen width and height depend upon the screen

Comment: , i have already used the mCanvas.drawBitmap(imageMask, 0, 0, paint), But the problem is recognition  x, y coordinates of mask1 and mask2 area to trigger event on its touch.